# Angular $http request not sending x-access-token

Tags: angularjs, http, http-headers, httprequest

I am trying to set up a Token based authentication, everything is working already, besides the `$http` requests not sendding the `x-access-token` header.

I is being pushed into the headers like so:

```
.config(function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
})
```

And here is the *AuthInterceptor* service function that happens on every request

```
AuthInterceptorFactory.request = function(config) {
    let token = AuthToken.getToken(); // gets the token from local storage
    if (token) config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
    return config;
}
```

This are the headers being send on the request

```
Accept:*/*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-access-token
Access-Control-Request-Method:GET
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/my-app/index.php
```

It works and sends the *x-access-token* if I add the token as a param on the request like so (ES6 syntax):

```
getAllLocutores(){
    let token = this.AuthToken.getToken();
    return this.http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: this.baseUrl,
      params: { token }
    });
}
```

But I guess that the headers are made so I don't have to send a token as a param on every request that requires it.

The *x-access-token* is being added to the config.headers but not send on the request.

These are the headers when I send the token as a param

```
Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Host:localhost:3000
Origin:http://localhost
Referer:http://localhost/my-app/index.php
x-access-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx
```

*With a the real token*

Answer (score 0):

This might work

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function() {
  return {
   'request': function(config) {
       let token = AuthToken.getToken();
       if (token) config.headers['x-access-token'] = token;
       return config;
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: It did not. Sorry I did not mention that the header is being add to the config request, but is just not being send. Adding it to the question.

Comment: Did you check if token is returned properly back like `console.log(AuthToken.getToken());` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. Because I do _AuthToken.getToken()_ to send it via the _request params_.

Comment: Did you do anything to test if 'request' above is executed at all? Like `console.log("I can see this shit...");` Just want to establish where problem is.

Comment: Yes, I logged the `config.headers` after adding the token. It does add it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
return this.http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: this.baseUrl,
  headers: {'x-access-token':token},
});
```

Comment: It does not work either. I guess the problem is the request is not sending the header.
_Access-Control-Request-Headers:accept, x-access-token_ the request for the header to be accepted is being send.

Comment: Is it possible for you to provide sample fiddlerjs or plunkr here? In my environment I could add request headers.

Comment: Right now I can't but I will as soon as I can. I did some more testing though. It only happens on Chrome and Firefox, IE sends the headers as well as POSTman